# CSS Grid column alignment

Tags: css, css-grid

I need to align columns to center, but with no luck. I tried justify-content, justify-items, align-items, but nothing works.

```
.row {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12,1fr);
  justify-content: center;
  align-items:center;
}

.col-2 {
  grid-column-start: span 2;
}

.col-4 {
  grid-column-start: span 4;
}
```

here is basic demo - https://jsfiddle.net/k0apdg5s/1/

EDIT:
What I really want to achieve is to align the last two cols to center in grid like this - http://jsfiddle.net/cez04sw4/2/

Comment: In your demo fiddle: do you need the items in the second row to center relative to the container?

Comment: Can you please specify your question. What is it you want to achieve?

Comment: Why not just margin: 0 auto; ?

Comment: why are you using css grid like flex? That is not what it is meant for. Grid is an **addition** to flex, not an replacement.

Answer (score 0):

Again as an complete answer: Why are you using css grid like flex? That is not what it is meant for. Grid is an addition to flex, not an replacement.

The correct answer here is to use `display: flex;` instead of `display: grid;`. You can use grid around a flex-container or use `justify-items` or `justify-self` with items in **the same** area.

Here is a correct working example:

```css
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items:center;
}

.col-2 {
  width: 16.66%; /* 100/6 */
}

.col-4 {
  width: 33.33%; /* 100/3 */
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col col-2">
    <img src="//placehold.it/240x240" />
  </div>
  <div class="col col-2">
    <img src="//placehold.it/240x240" />
  </div>
  <div class="col col-2">
    <img src="//placehold.it/240x240" />
  </div>
  <div class="col col-2">
    <img src="//placehold.it/240x240" />
  </div>
  <div class="col col-2">
    <img src="//placehold.it/240x240" />
  </div>
  <div class="col col-2">
    <img src="//placehold.it/240x240" />
  </div>
  <div class="col col-2">
    <img src="//placehold.it/240x240" />
  </div>
  <div class="col col-2">
    <img src="//placehold.it/240x240" />
  </div>
  <div class="col col-2">
    <img src="//placehold.it/240x240" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I've wanted to use grid because of the grid-auto-flow: dense; feature, which is not in the demo. http://jsfiddle.net/cez04sw4/2/ - here is complete demo, I want to align the last two cols to center, but I don't know if it's even possible with grid like this. Any ideas?